# How do I retrieve a string of taxonomy field terms associated with a node in Computed Field module?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, nodes, entities

I'm building a catalogue using Drupal 7 for a client (fashion retailer). For purposes of creating an efficient search system via Views, I have created a custom Computed Field (in plain text output) with the following concatenations:

```
$entity_field[0]['value'] = $entity->field_stylebrand['und'][0]['value'] . " " . $entity->title . " " . $entity->field_styledesc['und'][0]['value'];
```

Now, I want to ask how I can retrieve the taxonomy terms associated with this node (e.g. "black", "brown", and "navy" from vocabulary "colors") into a plain text string, simply separated by a white-space each (i.e. "black brown navy"), to add into my code?

Comment: I'm doing something similar, any joy? I'm hacking away at some EntityFieldQuery code, but its not working properly. I'm trying to find the term_id for the current term.. shouldn't be this hard!